# C# overload api method by object type

Tags: c#, generics, api-design

Is it possible to overload an api endpoint by object type in C#? Here is my attempt to overload `CreateDocument` endpoint with document types `Contract1` and `Contract2`,

```
[HttpPost("CreateDocument")]
public async Task<object> CreateDocument(CustomerDocument<Contract1> document)
{
    return CreateDocument<Contract1>(document);
}

[HttpPost("CreateDocument")]
public async Task<object> CreateDocument(CustomerDocument<Contract2> document)
{
    return CreateDocument<Contract2>(document);
}

private async Task<object> CreateDocument<T>(CustomerDocument<T> document) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

My Model

```
public class CustomerDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public T DocData { get; set; }

    public CustomerDocument(T initialValue)
    {
        DocData = initialValue;
    }
}
```

I get the error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints.

Comment: I would tend think it's not possible. Because AFAIK, the routing is done earlier than objects deserialization. Not with the exact same API path anyways.

Comment: No, you would need to manually extract the `document` based on pulling apart the incoming request. But why not just have 2 endpoints, so much simpler.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, I have a bunch, so I figured it would be easier for the front end to just use one endpoint instead of making a bunch of different endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know a shorter solution that would not use the dynamic object, but this allows using multiple object types in one api method by using an id and a switch statement.

```
[HttpPost("CreateDocument")]
public async Task<object> CreateDocument(dynamic document, int id)
{
    switch (id) {
        case 0:
            return await CreateDocument<Contract1>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDocument<Contract1>>(document));
        case 1:
            return await CreateDocument<Contract2>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDocument<Contract2>>(document));
        //other cases ...
        default:
            return Json("Error");
    }
}

private async Task<object> CreateDocument<T>(CustomerDocument<T> document) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. Also, you are now passing in an id, which means it would have been far easier to make a new endpoint instead. It would be simple code, easier to understand and more efficient. Please don't do this.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, so it's just better to have 100s of endpoints like `CreateDocumentContract1(CustomerDocument<Contract1> document)`?

Comment: Do you really have hundreds of different generic types or are you exaggerating? But sure, you're already having to choose the action by id so you may as well have more endpoints. You could automate creation of them all with source generator or T4 templates if you really do have so many.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks!! I'll design it that way, for some reason I just didn't like the idea of having so many endpoints for the same thing, but I agree using `dynamic` is a bad way to fix that.